# word for that time of the month where funds are running low and you gotta wait til payday

Tags: phrases, slang

Basically title, but is the meaning of the Indonesian phrase "tanggal Tua".
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the Indonesian phrase?  What is its literal translation?  Does it mean anything other than what you have in the title?  How would it be used in a sentence?

Comment: In American English we have the phrase "living from paycheck to paycheck" but I'm not familiar with any name for the last few days when people are looking under their sofa cushions for coins that may have fallen out of their pockets. Also, re "time of the month", those at the bottom end of the pay scale in the US are normally paid on a weekly not a monthly basis.

Comment: Another phrase used for living from paycheck to paycheck is "living hand-to-mouth". Still, this doesn't lend itself to a word for that time just before you get your paycheck.

Comment: That's known as having too much month left at the end of your money.

Answer (score 2):

This is called 'to make ends meet', simply! [Cambridge dictionaries online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-ends-meet)

In agriculture, there is 'the lean season' or 'hunger season' or 'hunger gap', the days or months that separate the running out of food reserves and the new harvest, which will replenish the granaries. [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/p%C3%A9riodes+de+soudure.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is an expression I've heard about there being

> "too much month at the end of the money"

this is a play on the more usual (and beneficial!) phrase where you would be considering to do with your excess money at the end of the month.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be what you would name that period of time.

You could try

> The end of the month

This makes an assumption that is true in most situations, that people are paid at the start or end of the month. It's usually understood:

> Would you like to go for a pint?
>   I can't, end of the month, you know?

A little less idiomatically, but you'd be understood if you referred to it as

> before payday

As in

> Money gets pretty tight before payday.